# Iteration can be replaced with bulk 'Collection.addAll'

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, duplicates

So my goal is to fill arraty with y random numbers from 1 to x section, and then count how many times each number is duplicated and print it.
Here is code:

```
int counter = 1;
    int length = random.length;
    Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(random[i] == random[i+1])
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            hashMap.put(random[i], counter);
            System.out.println(random[i] + " duplicate : " + counter + " times.");
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
```

And my problem is at if statment, it wont show how many times last number is buplicated, coz it will add one to counter and won't save it. How could I fix it? If you have ideas overall, how could I do this better way, then using for+if with array, go ahead and give me hint.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Java8+, you can use [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int n : random) {
    hashMap.merge(n, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Which reads as follows: *for every number `n` in the `random` array, put it in the map with value `1`, and if it's already present, sum `1` to its value*.

Comment: WOW, wow I have to say wow. You reaplaced 20 lines of code to 3 O_O.  Damn, that simply and in the other hand that smart. Thanks for help and really nice explained as well :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(random)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                               Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if key is present in hashMap if yes then get the value from that key and update with increment else add as new key value in hash map.

## before java8

example;

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < random.length; i++)
    if (hashMap.containsKey(random[i])) {
       hashMap.put(random[i], (hashMap.get(random[i])+1))
    } else {
       hashMap.put(random[i], 1)
    }
}
```

now key will present your random number and it value will present total number of duplicates

## with java8

```
    IntStream
            .range(0, random.length)
            .forEach(i -> {
                hashMap.compute(random[i], (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v +1);
            });
```

Comment: Both your statements are the same for your if/else. Using `compute` would be cleaner.

Comment: @PeterLawrey my bad, i did't update else condition, I have updated code with both before and after java8

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using a third-party library with primitive collections, there are a couple of approaches that will work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

Option 1: Use a [MutableIntIntMap](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/map/primitive/MutableIntIntMap.html)

```
MutableIntIntMap map = IntIntMaps.mutable.empty();
Arrays.stream(random).forEach(i -> map.addToValue(i, 1));
map.forEachKeyValue((k, v) ->
        System.out.println(k + " duplicate : " + v + " times."));
```

Option 2: Use a [MutableIntBag](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/primitive/MutableIntBag.html)

```
IntBags.mutable.with(random)
        .forEachWithOccurrences((i, counter) ->
                System.out.println(i + " duplicate : " + counter + " times."));
```

This [blog](https://medium.com/oracledevs/bag-the-counter-2689e901aadb) gives a good introduction to the `Bag` data structure in Eclipse Collections.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to iterate is as:

```
IntStream.range(0, length - 1).forEach(i -> {
    if (hashMap.containsKey(random[i])) {
        int current = hashMap.get(random[i]);
        hashMap.put(random[i], current + 1); // increment the count corresponding to the key
    } else {
        hashMap.put(random[i], 1); // initialise the count from 1
    }
});
// print the value and its count
hashMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " duplicate : " + value + " times."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `toMap`!

```
Arrays.stream(random).boxed().collect(toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1, Math::addExact));
```